# Chassis Grounding in Details

Tags: electricity

In an Earth Grounding the metal rod, burried deep into the ground, serves as an escape path for excessive electrons, thus preventing high potential difference between people and metal surfaces, if I am right.

Well, in a car, for example, how does the chassis of the car serve as an escape point for excessive electrons or how does big amounts of energy are dissipated when the car itself is on four insulators and has no connection to the ground.

How does this big piece of metal proccesses electrical faults? Also, what happens with the excessive electrons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circuitry of the car is an entirely self-contained system, as you point out, because it sits on rubber tires that disconnect it from the ground. So let's have a look at that system.

The power source for a car is the battery, which typically has its negative terminal very securely connected to the metal body of the car. Electrical loads in the car are supplied power from the positive terminal of the battery and the metal body of the car furnishes the return ("neutral") ground path for each of the loads, eliminating the need for a separate return wire and thereby saving money. This arrangement also means that the zero-voltage reference point (the "ground") is *also* the metal body of the car.

Here we note that in a house or a concrete building, neutral return wires must be provided in all load branches of the circuitry since the structure of the building is not metal and so cannot be used for that purpose.

We note also that the power source for a house is 120 or 220 volts which, unlike the 12VDC in a car, can be lethal if enough current driven by that voltage flows through your body for some reason.

Here's what this means:

If there is any fault or flaw whatsoever in the neutral return path for the house wiring and you yourself are contacting the "real" ground (the concrete floor or damp earth), current will want to flow through you instead and you'll get shocked.

But in the car, the neutral return is exactly the same thing as the ground reference and so there is no way you can "get yourself between" the neutral and the ground reference.

And even if you grabbed onto the +12 volt terminal of the battery with one hand and the metal body of the car with your other, there isn't enough voltage there to push enough current through your skin and into your body to injure or kill you.

Comment: Thanks for the decent explanations but still there is something I don't understand. What happens if a lot of excessive charge, if possible, is accumulated in the metal body of the car, but the voltage is not high enough for the current to go to the ground. For example a faulty wire is touching the chassis, thus shorting the circuit. This will mean that the excessive charge is trapped into the car until something dischrages it, which may be a person.

Comment: that happens to me in dry conditions- when I exit the car and touch the metal window frame I will get a static electric shock. this would not happen if the car body were connected to the roadway ground before I touched the  window frame.

Answer (score 0):

> Well, in a car, for example, how does the chassis of the car serve as
>   an escape point for excessive electrons or how does big amounts of
>   energy are dissipated when the car itself is on four insulators and
>   has no connection to the ground.

If you bring excessive charge inside a car, for instance, by charging yourself outside the car and then getting in, the charge will escape to the car at the first opportunity, for instance, if you touch the ignition switch. This happens because the charges always try to distribute themselves over the outer surface of a conductor to be at maximum distance from each other. The charge won't flow to the ground, since, as you've noted, the tires are not good conductors of electricity. So, it'll just sit on the outer surface of the car for some time until dissipates into environment.

If a car gets hit by a lightning, the discharge flows to the ground through the car - not to the car. For tremendous voltage levels involved in this case, the distance from the car to the ground is insignificant to be broken through, particularly, in comparison with the distance the lightning has to travel all the way from a cloud.